# Is there a pure-css solution to having position: fixed, bottom: 0 while scrolling body on iOS10?

Tags: ios, css

iOS will hide the bottom bar with controls when scrolling the body and elements that are `position: fixed` will not update their height or position it seems. So when the controls disappear there's a gap.

The only solution seem to be to poll for window height. Is there a pure CSS solution available to us?